# How do I pass data to meteor method?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, meteor

I'm working on a way to upload to an AWS S3 bucket from a meteor server and react frontend.

I have defined the following files

`server/methods.js`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3_bucket = "bucket-name"

import { mediaFiles } from '../imports/api/files.collection';

const s3  = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: '<key>',
    secretAccessKey: '<secret>',
    endpoint: 's3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    region: 'eu-west-2',
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
});

Meteor.methods({
    'aws.getUploadId' (filename, filetype) {
        let params = {
            Bucket: s3_bucket,
            Key: filename,
            ContentType: filetype
        }
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            s3.createMultipartUpload(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) reject(err)
                if (data) resolve(data.UploadId)
            })
        })
    },

    'aws.uploadPart' (filename, blob, upload_id, index) {
        let params = {
            Bucket: s3_bucket,
            Key: filename,
            PartNumber: index,
            UploadId: upload_id,
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            s3.uploadPart(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) reject(err)
                if (data) resolve(data)
            })
        })
    },

    'aws.completeUpload' (filename, upload_id, upload_parts) {
        console.log("aws.completeUpload called")
        console.log(`filename: ${filename}\nID: ${upload_id}\nUpload_parts****${upload_parts}****`)
        let params = {
            Bucket: s3_bucket,
            Key: filename,
            UploadId: upload_id,
            MultipartUpload: {Parts: upload_parts}
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            s3.completeMultipartUpload(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) reject(err)
                if (data) resolve(data)
            })
        })
    },
});
```

`upload.js # client side`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Page, Icon, ProgressBar, Input, Select } from 'react-onsenui';
import _ from 'underscore';

import Navbar from './Navbar';

class Upload extends Component {

    state = { 
        uploadId : '',
        media_file : null,
        filename : '' 
    }

    setUploadFileParameters = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('setUploadFileParameters called')
        const media_file = e.target.files[0]
        const filename = media_file.name
        const filetype = media_file.type

        Meteor.call('aws.getUploadId', filename, filetype, (err, res) => {
            if (err) console.log("Error getting id: ", err)
            if (res) {
                this.setState({ media_file: media_file, filename: filename, uploadId: res })
            }
        })
    }

    uploadIt = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const t = e.target
        const upload_id = this.state.uploadId
        const media_file = t.media_file.files[0]
        console.log(`mediafile: ${media_file}`)

        try {
            const FILE_CHUNK_SIZE = 10000000 // 10MB
            const fileSize = media_file.size
            const filename = media_file.name
            const NUM_CHUNKS = Math.round(fileSize / FILE_CHUNK_SIZE) + 1
            let start, end, blob
            let upload_parts = []

            for (let index = 1; index < NUM_CHUNKS + 1; index++) {
                start = (index - 1)*FILE_CHUNK_SIZE
                end = (index)*FILE_CHUNK_SIZE
                blob = (index < NUM_CHUNKS) ? media_file.slice(start, end) : media_file.slice(start)

                // Puts each file part into the storage server
                Meteor.call('aws.uploadPart', filename, blob, upload_id, index, (err, res) => {
                    if (err) console.log("uploading part error ", err)
                    if (res) {
                        // console.log("RES: ", typeof res, res)
                        upload_parts.push({Etag: res.ETag, PartNumber: index})    
                    }
                })
            }

            // Generate the parts list to complete the upload
            // Calls the CompleteMultipartUpload endpoint in the backend server
            console.log("upload_parts: ", upload_parts)

            Meteor.call('aws.completeUpload', filename, upload_id, upload_parts, (err, res) => {
                console.log("Complete upload called *****")
                if (err) console.log("Complete upload err: ", err)
                if (res) console.log("Complete upload res: ", res)
            })
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { showMenu } = this.props
        console.log("State: ", JSON.stringify(this.state))

            return (
                <Page renderToolbar={Navbar('Upload', showMenu)}>
                    <div className="form-container">

                    {Meteor.user() &&
                        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.uploadIt(e)}>

                            <p>File</p>

                            <Input
                                type="file"
                                id="fileinput"
                                ref="fileinput"
                                name="media_file"
                                onChange={e => this.setUploadFileParameters(e)}
                            />
                            <br/>

                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                value="Upload"
                                className="btn upload-work-button" 
                            >
                                Upload
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    }
                    </div>
                </Page>
            )
        }
    }
export default Upload;
```

The problem I have is that the `upload_parts` content is not being passed to the meteor backend server. A console log on the back end server doesn't return anything. It doesn't even return `undefined`.
I need help with this.

Comment: Did you import `server/methods.js` in `server/main.js` ?

Comment: Yes. I did. All other methods are working correctly

Comment: also `Meteor.call` is async, so upload_parts will be empty when you'll send it

Comment: Please explain a little bit more.

Comment: `Meteor.call` takes a callback function, so when you call `Meteor.call('aws.uploadPart' ...` and you push objects in it it will be after `Meteor.call('aws.completeUpload'`

Comment: I was thinking the `for...`  loop will complete before we get to `Meteor.call('aws.completeUpload',..`. This line `console.log("upload_parts: ", typeof upload_parts, upload_parts)` shows the correct output.

Comment: Meteor.call is Async that's why you have a callback

Comment: Is it a requirement to upload the file to the server? ¿Can you upload the file to aws directly from the client? If so I can suggest another solution.

Comment: Please do suggest. Thing is files might get bigger which is why I wanted to have multipart uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Nathan Schwarz for your response. You really helped me on this one. Here's how I finally solved my puzzle.

```
const uploadParts = (filename, blob, upload_id, index) => {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => 
        Meteor.call('aws.uploadPart', filename, blob, upload_id, index, (err, res) => {
            resolve(res)
        })
    )
}

for (let index = 1; index < NUM_CHUNKS; index++) {
    start = (index - 1)*FILE_CHUNK_SIZE
    end = (index)*FILE_CHUNK_SIZE
    blob = (index < NUM_CHUNKS) ? media_file.slice(start, end) : media_file.slice(start)

    const b = new Blob([blob], {type:filetype})
    const c = {size: blob.size, type:filetype}
    console.log("Media ", media_file.size, media_file)
    console.log("Blob: ", blob.size, blob)
    console.log("B: ", b.size, b)

    promises.push(uploadParts(filename, c, upload_id, index))
}

Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
    res.forEach((r, index) => 
        upload_parts.push({ETag: r.ETag, PartNumber: index+1})
    )
    console.log("upload_parts: ", upload_parts)
    Meteor.call('aws.completeUpload', filename, upload_id, upload_parts, (err, res) => {
        if (err) console.log("Complete upload err: ", err)
        if (res) console.log("Complete upload res: ", res)
    })
})
```

With this code `upload_parts` is completed before `Meteor.call('aws.completeUpload',...)`

Take note of how I resolved the promises in `uploadParts`. It follows from how the backend server works. I can only get the return value from the backend if I pass a callback to `Meteor.call()`. The backend itself returns a promise as seen below.

```
'aws.uploadPart' (filename, blob, upload_id, index) {
    console.log("aws.uploadPart method")

    console.log("file blob: ", blob)
    console.log("filename: ", filename)

    let params = {
        Bucket: s3_bucket,
        Key: filename,
        PartNumber: index,
        UploadId: upload_id,
        Body: blob,
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.uploadPart(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            if (data) {
                console.log("Upload part return ", data)
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array is empty because you call asyncs functions to fill the array, so meteor delete it when you send it to the server.

you need to fill the arrays synchronously, or wrap them into promises.

```
    ....
    const uploadParts = (filename, blob, upload_id, index) => {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(
       Meteor.call('aws.uploadPart', filename, blob, upload_id, index, (err, res) => {
           upload_parts.push({Etag: res.ETag, partNumber: res.index})
       }))
    }
    let promises = []
    for (let index = 1; index < NUM_CHUNKS + 1; index++) {
        start = (index - 1)*FILE_CHUNK_SIZE
        end = (index)*FILE_CHUNK_SIZE
        blob = (index < NUM_CHUNKS) ? media_file.slice(start, end) : 
        media_file.slice(start)
        promises.push(uploadParts(filename, blob, upload_id, index))
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
       Meteor.call('aws.completeUpload', filename, upload_id, upload_parts, (err, res) => {
          console.log("Complete upload called *****")
          if (err) console.log("Complete upload err: ", err)
          if (res) console.log("Complete upload res: ", res)
       })
    })
```

---

check the documentation here ('asyncCallback'): https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call

Comment: I tried this. The problem is that the promises resolve  early on, and instead of the method calls to return `promises`, they return the resolved values. So the line `Promise.all(promises).then(res => )` has `res` as `undefined`

Comment: @chidimo I updated it, try to wrap Meteor.call in a Promise object

Comment: If it doesn't work try to modify 'aws.uploadPart' in the server side, and send and array containing all the chunks (to avoid multiple Meteor.call)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the return value of `Meteor.call()` is a only accessible via a callback function. Without that callback function I can't get the return value of `Meteor.call()`

Comment: then use a callback in Meteor.call, but keep it in a promise - I've just edited the answer